# set value for listboxitem templated binding

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem, templatebinding, itemcontainerstyle

I have this style:

```
<Style x:Key="SelectableListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

                <Border Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        CornerRadius="4"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        x:Name="IconBorder"
                        Margin="4,2,4,2">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="IconBorder" 
                                Property="BorderBrush" 
                                Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My problem is that I don't know which property to set on the ListBox, when consuming my style so that the borders of it's ListBoxItems would end up having the desired border brush. I would also like to make this work for the other border brush in my style.

I would like to be able to have two list boxes with this same style but different border colors. I have this for a ListBox:

```
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProduct.Pictures}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSet, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey= SelectableListBoxItemStyle}">
    </ListBox>
```

Update..I tried this:

```
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProduct.Pictures}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSet, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource SelectableListBoxItemStyle}">
                    <Setter TargetName="IconBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ListBox>
```

But, I get:
Error   8   TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `TemplateBinding` you should try using a relative source binding.

```
BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                      AncestorType={x:Type Listbox}}, 
                                      Path=BorderBrush}"
```

If you want to have a different border than that defined for the `ListBox` then you will need to add a brush resource to your `ResourceDictionary` and apply that instead:

```
<Listbox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyListBoxItemBorderBrush" Color="Red"/>
<Listbox.Resources>
```

and then in your template:

```
BorderBrush="{StaticResource MyListBoxItemBorderBrush}"
```

If you need certain items to have different borders then you need to look at a [StyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See, I already set the item container style of the listbox to 'SelectableListBoxItemStyle' that is pasted in my question. The problem is in 'BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"'. How do I *set* this when I consume the Style in xaml? Ie. which property should I set on the list box so that the border of my ListBoxItem ends up having the set border brush?

Comment: Thanks again. The 2nd one works, but now my ListBox needs to have the same BorderBrush as it's ListBoxItems, which isn't all that great. I edited my question to add an update, maybe you can fix that :)

Comment: Oh, a nice one! The resource trick nailed it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think you may need a custom control for that.  A least I know you can do it with a custom control!

If you create a custom control, extending from ListBox, that includes this style you've created, you can then create an attached property in it (something like ItemBorderColor) that you could bind to your border's BorderColor (actually, for a selection effect, you may want to create a trigger on you ControlTemplate () that applies that "ItemBorderColor" value to the border's BorderColor based on the "IsSelected" property).

There may be a pure XAML way to do it, but I do not know it....

Comment: yes, that would work. i'll stick around, maybe something pops up. it'd be a shame if this couldn't be done with just a style..

Comment: Looking at Benjamin's answer, it confirms that you will need some kind of memory container (or Property) to store the value of the "ItemBorderColor".  This is where (I think) XAML falls short as it will not let you "create" a new property in a style.
I might be wrong here though...